# Why is both sides of the if else statement being executed, and how to fix it?

Tags: android, if-statement, keyevent

I have a block of code:

```
passwordEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
        {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                launch.performClick();
                return true;

            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

What I want is that when the enter key is pressed it performs the log in command (launch is the button that executes the log in). However, after executing the true block, it continues on to execute the else block as well, returning false and causing (only on some devices) the log in to occur a second time.

So my question is in two parts: How can a if else statement evaluate as both true and false, and how can I make it so it doesn't do that. I have thought of a couple of tricks to make that happen but this seems to be a problem that is better understood then quickly patched.

Comment: Furthermore, if I reverse it so that it is keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER it goes to the correct block (the else block) but then it runs it twice anyways!

Comment: Did you try logging method calls to this event handler? It seems it is processing another event after the Enter is pressed. An else statement won't evaluate as both true and false, there is no way any compiler will have such a bizarre bug, so you need to assume that is not what's causing your problem.

Comment: its a double fire of the even one for key down and one for keyup

Comment: So onKey is getting called twice.  Look at the value of keyCode while stepping through your debugger to see what is getting passed to the second call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are seeing is the OnKey is fired twice, the first time for key down, and the second time for key up, so you have to filter it with

```
    if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        return true;
    }

    switch (keyCode) {
       case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1 : 
            //do something
            break;
       case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2 : 
            //do something
            break;
       case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3 : 
            //do something
            break;
    }

    return true;
```

Comment: That was totally it. I knew something was missing!

Comment: you should also check that FLAG_CANCELED is not set, if (event.getFlags() & KeyEvent.FLAG_CANCELED != 0) {//event was canceled}

Comment: @Mark yes you are correct need to check this too.  Also I've seen some issues with just using the onKeyDown where it doesn't get fired for some odd reason so stick with the onKey event

Comment: @JPM I think that issue most often happens as a result of an upstream handler not being written properly or otherwise intercepting the call.  When you return true from the handler the event propagation is halted and thus will not make it to any up stream handlers.  If you need to do something but still need the event to propagate then false should actually be returned.  This shows up a lot more in Views as there is default behavior for some View widgets which will snag the event and halt propagation up the view tree if the default behavior isn't overridden.

Comment: I don't know how many times I have run int this but now I just know that OnKey will always do a down and up, makes sense but easily overlooked when first dealing with it.

Comment: Funny how this can affect even seasoned programmers, I just ran into this today on another piece of old code I am supporting and took me a while to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The debugger can be misleading when a conditional outcome just leads to a return statement. Put in a useless 'int x variable' and have it assign x = 2 (say) before the return true and x = 3 (say) before the return false. Step through again in the debugger, I'll bet you see it entering only one of the blocks

Answer (score 1):

try with this code...

passwordEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() 
    {

```
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
        {
            launch.performClick();
            return true;

        }
        return false;

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not possible. The code you posted looks correct, so I wonder if there's an error that's not in the snippet you posted.

That said, some coding mistakes could lead a programmer to believe that both "if" and "else" blocks are being executed. E.g.

```
if(condition) {
  // do something
}
else; // note the semicolon here
{
  // do something else
  // this gets executed regardless of whether the condition is true!
}
```

But even then, if you have a "return" in your "if" block, there's no way you could get to the 2nd block :)

Comment: The code is copied and pasted from the program verbatim and I walked through in debug mode one line at a time and watched what happens.

Comment: Well, what happens after "return true" in the "if" block?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple events are fired when a key is pressed (or held, or released).

Specifically for a press and release the following are fired:

ACTION_DOWN

ACTION_DOWN (if held, with non-zero repeatCount, event possibly repeated multiple times)

ACTION_UP (possibly with the FLAG_CANCELED set if the event was canceled)

Your code does not check the action property and thus will be run every time an event is sent that involves the enter key.

Replace

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
```

with

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
```

if you only want this to fire once, when the key is released.  Checking for the ACTION_DOWN requires additional filtering to avoid multiple fires due to key repeating.  You probably also want to check the status of the FLAG_CANCELED when the ACTION_UP occurs.